# Cannot SSH To Microsoft Azure Linux VM (Ubuntu 17.10)

Tags: azure, ssh, virtual-machine

I created a new Linux VM (Ubuntu 17.10), and trying to connect to SSH through CloudShell, but the command `ssh suren@40.71.218.244` take forever and does not connect.

[image]

Port 22 is enabled.

[image]

I tried telnet from my local mac, and able to connect

```
telnet> open suren.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com 22
Trying 40.71.218.244...
Connected to suren.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5p1 Ubuntu-10ubuntu0.1
Connection closed by foreign host. here
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Your VM is running?

Comment: If you type `Enter` in screeshot what is the result?

Comment: Like this screenshot https://imgur.com/a/IuM2B ?

Comment: I test in my lab, your VM is running?  https://imgur.com/a/oSJNI   You need type your password.

Comment: If possible, could you use SSH tool to connect your VM, like putty?

Comment: Like I mentioned in my post, it takes a long time before I see a timeout. The option for password comes when it connects to VM. Cloudhsell is not able to make a connection to show me the password option. And yes VM is running (screenshot), and like I mentionein 3rd screenshot, I'm able to telnet from an external computer.

Comment: Yes, I think you could ssh to Azure VM on your local PC.

Comment: Why is my question downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

After trying several things, a hard-refresh of browser and re-login to Azure Portal did the trick. After i login, i could see the option to "Request a cloudhsell and choose the type".

Adding screenshots, may help others.

[image: Azure create cloudshell]

[image: Azure cloudshell created]

[image: Azure ssh/logged into vm]

Answer (score 0):

From the above troubleshooting that has been done the only conclusion is that you are in a restricted network that block port 22.

You can use Port Query tools like tcping, psping or portqry to determine if port 22 (Default SSH Port) is listening. If you system can't communicated over port 22 then you might want to try when connected to a different network.

Comment: Thanks! And yes, Port 22 was allowed (in my screenshot), and i was able to SSH from external system (ssh in mac-terminal).

Comment: Great!!  The restricted network i was talking about is not the Azure network but your local network, you can see that from the portal.